# How do I get and download the contents of a file in GitHub using the REST API?

Tags: rest, github, curl, azure-devops

I am trying to use the GitHub API to retrieve and download the contents of a file in my GitHub repository to mimic how I am using the Azure DevOps REST API.

My ADO URL is:

```
https://dev.azure.com/<Org>/<Project>/_apis/git/repositories/<Repository>/items?versionType=branch&version=develop&path=<Path to file>/DEV1.yml&download=true
```

Above works perfectly fine and if I type that into my browser, it immediately downloads the `DEV1.yml` file.

I am trying to mimic this implementation using GitHub's [REST API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/contents). My URL looks like:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/<Org>/<Repository>/contents/<Path to file>/DEV1.yml&download=true
```

This GitHub URL does not work in the browser, I assume it's because the repo is private and I need a token. However when I use curl:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <PAT>" https://api.github.com/repos/<Org>/<Repository>/contents/<Path to file>/DEV1.yml&download=true
```

This returns a large base64 encoded JSON object. I attempted to use the URL in place of the existing ADO one and it failed.

Are the 2 above URLs not the same?

Comment: The url you are using now should be used to get the 'file actual content url', it is a necessary step. However, the content of the file cannot be captured only through this url, and the specific file data must be obtained by re-requesting the download_url attribute in the return value of this url request.

Comment: As a command line file transfer tool, curl may not be able to implement complex logic, you need some code to implement the logic. I provide a python example, if you are not familiar with python and need a code example, please tell me what language you are good at and I can write an example for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is different.

Github REST API download files has two steps.

***1, The first step is get the download url.***

The url format like this:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/<Project Name>/<Repository Name>/contents/<File Name>
```

The response format like this:

[image]

***2, The second step is using the download url to get the file content.***

The url format like this:

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/<Project Name>/<Repository Name>/main/<File Name>?token=<Random Token that related to Revision Version>
```

**Please notice that the first step can't skip, otherwise you will be unable to get the revision token.**

I can achieve your requirement using python:

```
import requests

#Define required information
project_name = "xxx"
repository_name = "xxx"
# repository_name = "xxx"
branch_name = "xxx"
File_name = "xxx"
PAT = "xxx"
url = "https://api.github.com/repos/"+project_name+"/"+repository_name+"/contents/"+File_name

#downoad file from github
payload = {}
headers = {
    'Authorization': 'token '+PAT
}

#download file
file_content = requests.request("GET", ((requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)).json())['download_url'], headers=headers, data=payload)
print(file_content.text)
```

Successfully get the latest contents(I am also based on private repository):

[image]